# How should i set mvcoptions.enableendpointrouting in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have added what I have tired , I'm trying to set mvcoptions.enableendpointrouting in ConfigureServices method

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                DeveloperExceptionPageOptions developerExceptionPageOptions = new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions()
                {
                    SourceCodeLineCount = 1
                };
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(developerExceptionPageOptions);
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the site. You can enable/disable endpoint routing the following way:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
           ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it this way:

```
    builder.Services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

While the builder is where you are getting your app from

```
WebApplication app = builder.BuildApp();
```